# I keep getting invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, networking, ip

[This is the image for the code, pls help me out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db9HB.png)

I tried putting closing parentheses on sock.sendto(int(bytes,(ip, port)) but it doesn't work, that is what people have been saying on Reddit

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include code **and** data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

On line number 30 you have opened 3 brackets and closed only 2

Your syntax error is because of brackets imbalance

Answer (score 0):

You should use 3 closing bracket like this

```
socket.sendto(int(bytes,(ip,port)))
```